# AWS Sagemaker CustomerError: Encoding Mismatch when monitoring input

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've deployed a Pipeline model in AWS and am now trying to use ModelMonitor to assess incoming data behavior, but it failes when **generating monitoring report**

The pipeline consists of a preprocessing step and then a regular XGBoost container. The model is invoked with `Content-type: application/json`.

For that I set up as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1896), but it fails with the following error

> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.sagemaker.dataanalyzer.exception.CustomerError: Error: Encoding mismatch: Encoding is JSON for endpointInput, but Encoding is CSV for endpointOutput. We currently only support the same type of input and output encoding at the moment.

I've found this [issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1896) at GitHub, but didn't help me.

Digging depper into how XGBoost outputs, I've found out that it's CSV encoded, hence the error makes sense, but even deploying the model enforcing the serializers fails (code in the section below)

I'm configuring the schedule as recommended by AWS, I've just changed the location of my constraints (had to manually adjust'em)

---> Tried so far (all attempts fail with the exact same error)

1. As mentioned in the issue, but since I'm expecting a json payload, I've used

```
data_capture_config=DataCaptureConfig(
    enable_capture = True,
    sampling_percentage=100,
    json_content_types = ['application/json'],
    destination_s3_uri=MY_BUCKET)
```

2. Tried enforcing the (de)serializer of the predictor (I'm not sure if that even makes sense)

```
predictor = Predictor(
    endpoint_name=MY_ENDPOINT,
    # Hoping that I could force the output to be a JSON
    deserializer=sagemaker.deserializers.JSONDeserializer)
```

and later

```
predictor = Predictor(
    endpoint_name=MY_ENDPOINT,
    # Hoping that I could force the input to be a CSV
    serializer=sagemaker.serializers.CSVSerializer)
```

3. Setting (de)serializer during deploy

```
p_modle = pipeline_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
    endpoint_name=MY_ENDPOINT,
    serializer = sagemaker.serializers.JSONSerializer(),
    deserializer= sagemaker.deserializers.JSONDeserializer(),
    wait = True)
```

Comment: It seems to me that I need to deserialize the answer itself before being fed into model monitor, but I can't do so   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html#ir-deserialization

Answer (score -1):

I have come across a similar issue earlier while invoking the endpoint using boto3 sagemaker runtime. Try adding the 'Accept' parameter in invoke_endpoint function with value as 'application/json'.

refer for more help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html#API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint_RequestSyntax

Comment: the problem isn't getting back json or csv upon invoking the endpoint yourself, the problem is that model monitor must be invoking the endpoint itself and there's no apparent way to configure model monitor's invocations to specifically set InvokeEndpoint's Accept parameter.

Comment: basically, how can we configure the endpoint to always send back a specific content type that matches the input content type so that model monitor can capture and monitor?