# AWS Sagemaker Monitoring Error: Encoding mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, monitoring, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run model monitoring on a model in AWS Sagemaker. The monitoring jobs are failing due to **" Encoding mismatch: Encoding is JSON for endpointInput, but Encoding is base64 for endpointOutput. We currently only support the same type of input and output encoding at the moment."**

Encoding is JSON for endpointInput and base64 for endpointOutput but the expected is json for both input and output.

I tried using the json_content_types in the DataCaptureConfig but the endpointOutput is still in base64 encoded.

Below is my DataCaptureConfig which i used in the deploy :

```
data_capture_config=DataCaptureConfig(
enable_capture = True,
sampling_percentage=100,
json_content_types = 'application/json',
destination_s3_uri=MY_BUCKET)
```

My capture files from the model looks something like this:

```
{
"captureData": {
"endpointInput": {
"observedContentType": "application/json",
"mode": "INPUT",
"data": "{ === json data ===}",
"encoding": "JSON"
},
"endpointOutput": {
"observedContentType": "*/*",
"mode": "OUTPUT",
"data": "{====base 64 encoded output ===}",
"encoding": "BASE64"
}
},
"eventMetadata": {
=== some metadata ===
}
```

I have observed that the output content type is not being recognized as the json/application.
So I need a workaround/procedure to get the output in the json encoded form.
Please help to the get JSON encoding for both input and output data.

Similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836468/aws-sagemaker-customererror-encoding-mismatch-when-monitoring-input) , but there is no response.

Answer (score 1):

While deploying the endpoint please set the CaptureContentTypeHeader in the DataCaptureConfig and appropriately map the output either Json ontentTypes or CsvContentTypes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CaptureContentTypeHeader.html

Doing this would set the encoding accordingly . If this is not set the default is base64 encoding and hence the issue .

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar issue earlier while invoking the endpoint using boto3 sagemaker-runtime. Try adding the 'Accept' request parameter in invoke_endpoint function with value as 'application/json'.

refer for more help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html#API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint_RequestSyntax